# c++ [diamond configuration] How to initialize with inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, diamond-problem

I apologize if my question is dumb but i'm a beginner in c++. I'm working on diamond inheritance and i would like to know if it is possible to choose the specific parent class which will initilize an attribute for the child class.

To sum up, i would like this code to output `B`

Thank you for your answers !

PS: i'm working with c++98

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    protected:
        char    m_char;
    public:
        A(): m_char('A'){};
        char    getChar(){return m_char;};
        ~A(){};
};

class B : virtual public A
{
    private:
        
    public:
        B() {m_char = 'B';};
        ~B(){};
};

class C : virtual public A
{
    private:
        
    public:
        C() {m_char = 'C';};
        ~C(){};
};

class D : public B, public C
{
    private:
        
    public:
        D() {m_char = B::m_char;};
        ~D(){};
};

int main(void)
{
    D   d;
    std::cout << d.getChar() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `class D : public C, public B {};`?

Answer (score 1):

Virtual base classes are initialized In depth-first, left-to-right order. So you would need to name B second in your inheritance for D to call its constructor last and thus setting the variable to B at the end.

```
class D : public C, public B
```

Comment: *"to name B second"* pseudo appropriated to propose to reorder letter :-)

Comment: Yes, i noticed it. But i would like to know if there is a way to choose from which class it shoul inherit. For exemple : if i have two attributes, one inherits frome B and another one from C. Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: you mean if you declare a member variable in B and C with the same name? That is not possible. If you have a variable `foo` defined in B and C then you can access it like this: `d.B::foo`

Answer (score 0):

`m_char = B::m_char;` is self assignment (there is only one `m_char`).

In virtual inheritance, it is the most derived class which initialize the virtual class (body does assignment).

How about being explicit in construction:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
protected:
    char m_char;
public:
    A() : m_char('A') {}
    char getChar() const { return m_char; }
    virtual ~A() {}
};

class B : virtual public A
{
public:
    B() : A('B') {}
};

class C : virtual public A
{
public:
    C() : A('C') {}
};

class D : public B, public C
{
public:
    D() : A('B'), B(), C() {}
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    std::cout << d.getChar() << std::endl;
}
```